# Why do we need the spectral theorem? What is its purpose?

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

One realization of spectral theorem for me that we want to make sense  "the object $:f(T)$"  in von Neumann algebra $M$ where $f$ is bounded measurable function with respect to some measure.

1. Classifying seperable representation for commutative $C^*$-algebras but why one need to classify in canonical way?

Essentialy abelian $vN$ algebras isomorphic to $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ is nothing but spectral theorem, still some gaps are there so I am feeling why spectral theorem is so important, can people give more different respectives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spectral Theorem says that any selfadjoint (normal, really) operator is an integral over its spectrum with respect to a projection-valued measure. As you say, this allows one to do bounded Borel functional calculus. This for instance serves to show that von Neumann algebras have many projections; so many that any von Neumann algebra is the norm-closure of the span of its projections. Approximating a selfadjoint operator, in norm, by linear combinations of projections is a basic technique that is used in many many proofs.